# Building Node application that has services that are somewhat coupled

Tags: node.js

I am building a Node application that has a front end standard API for a SPA and a backend service that is constantly polling another API, I am going through the Node documentation in regards to clustering, forking and workers and am a bit confused and am unable to come across anything that adequately addresses the question I have.

I would like to have the 2 different API's on 2 different server cores but use the same codebase. I have experimented with 2 node entrance files `app.js` and `app1.js` both work just fine on the same server, but this was a very very simple implementation.

Is this wise to do? As stated above I will need to have the same codebase available for both services to perform business logic.

I am having a hard time finding examples or envisioning what this would look like, would I just do the 2 `app.js` entrance files? What about getting these services on different processor cores? Is this possible? I am assuming I could communicate between them using IPC? But do I use clustering? Forking?

A quick and simple example would be very useful as I am still pretty new and this is very advanced for me at this stage but I just need a small boost in how to get this rolling. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do you need 2 different API's on 2 different server cores?

Comment: Maybe it's naivety but they are different services, one is a web stream that gets trading quotes and the other is input from users. In my mind, they would be separate. Your saying I would be ok to run them on the same core? At the same time if I need to scale one side of the application or the other wouldn't it be better to have them seperate?

Comment: okay now I think I get what you are looking for, but then again I don't think you need to have 2 different entry files. you could write the code in such a way that (clustering)[https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html] is used, so you can probably get trading quotes in a worker process and the user input one in the master process.